# Having trouble doing dynamic width dropdowns with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the dropdown itself working just fine, but I need to find a way to make the width dynamic. The issue I'm having is that I need to be able to float ul's next to each other in either 2 or 3 columns. I know I can simply add a class to set the width as needed, but I'm hoping to find a way with css that will be more dynamic, kind of like the trick using white-space: nowrap; on the li of a single column within the dropdown.
Right now my code is the basic bootstrap dropdown set up.

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle arrow down-arrow" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Item</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
         <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I had to do was switch the position on .dropdown to static, put the relative on .nav, and switch the left on .dropdown-menu from 0 to auto.

Comment: One of the many reasons why bootstrap is complicated to use and may not be right for every project.

Comment: I agree. I don't really like it, but the client insisted.